# ng-options with keys of different types

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, typescript, ng-options

I use AngularJS  and TypeScript. I want to connect two select elements via a common model variable. In the controller, I have two key-value-arrays, one with numbers as keys, and the other with strings as keys, like this:

```
foo: IKeyValuePair[] = [
             {key: 1, value: "koko"},
             {key: 2, value: "hoho"},
             {key: 3, value: "jojo"}
    ];
bar: IKeyValuePair[] = [
             {key: "1", value: "kaka"},
             {key: "2", value: "haha"},
             {key: "3", value: "jaja"}
    ];
```

In the view, I have two selects:

```
    Foo-selector: <select ng-model="vm.baz" 
        ng-options="f.key as f.value for f in vm.foo"></select>

    Bar-selector: <select ng-model="vm.baz" 
        ng-options="f.key as f.value for f in vm.bar"></select>
```

I want them to be connected via the model, vm.baz, but the problem is that the keys of foo are numbers and the key for bar are strings. Is there a way to connect them anyway? (I cannot change the types of the keys in either of the arrays).

Here is a fiddle: http://fiddlesalad.com/typescript/ngoptions-selected-by-model

Comment: Note: object references are different ..will need `track by`. Can't you just copy and normalize copies to be used for `ng-options`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert one of the keys to the other type.

For example you could convert the number to a string.

Since you can use expressions as values or keys all you really need to do is make it a string. Easiest would be to add an empty string at the end.

```html
Foo-selector:
<select ng-model="vm.baz" ng-options="f.key + '' as f.value for f in vm.foo">
```

If you want to make both keys a number you will need to make a method in the controller to convert the string to number because parseInt is not available in angular expressions.

Controller:

```js
    normalize(value): number {
      return parseInt(value, 10);
    }
```

Template:

```html
Bar-selector:
<select ng-model="vm.baz" ng-options="vm.normalize(f.key) as f.value for f in vm.bar">
```

Comment: Both methods works fine. Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!